# How to 'kill' the threads from an executor?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks

I have an tomcat webapp where I use a java executor to execute some runnables.

First I allocate the executor service from my executor instance like this:

```
executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads, new MyThreadFactory(threadFactoryName))
```

Then, I launch task using the executor service:

```
executorService.execute(new MyRunnable);
```

Then, it seems to work. But my problem is, I am chasing some sort of leak where I get this error after a while of running the server:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderCorePoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:703)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:652)
at something.server.ThreadExecutor.execute(MyRunnable.java:91)
```

I used the java VisualVM on tomcat instance to trace the thread allocation. I see that when I call 'newFixedThreadPool' I see 'nThreads' new threads. But after their job is done, I see the state of the threads to be on 'wait'.

Is that normal? I don't believe it is, I know the runnables finish their job but the executor service never frees the threads. What can I do to free them, or am I completely out of scope?

Comment: Not sure, I got you right but a pool really implies that the pooled objects (here threads) are reused. So it's normal... For the OOM: Are you using ThreadLocals?

Comment: I thought that the whole thing about a *fixed* ThreadPool was that it has always the same number of Threads? In your ThreadFactory, can you give the Threads a specific name and then Profile if it is the thread from that executor that are going wild? I guess they are not and it is some other leak.

Comment: are you running on 32bit or 64bit os?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are instantiating a new `ExecutorService` for every request, or something like that.

You should either instantiate only one `ExecutorService`, and reuse it, or call `shutdown()` on the service after you have finished submitting tasks. The `shutdown` function will wait for the tasks to finish, and then free the threads.

Answer (score 2):

> Is that normal? I don't believe it is, I know the runnables finish their job but the executor service never frees the threads.

Yes it is normal.  Indeed, this behaviour is desirable because creating a new thread is an expensive operation.  The pool threads (or at least the 'core' pool threads) will continue to exist until the executor gets shut down.

> What can I do to free them, or am I completely out of scope?

You should be able to configure your thread pool to have a smaller 'core' thread pool, and/or a smaller keepAlive time.  Refer to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for details.

---

> [M]y problem is, I am chasing some sort of leak where I get this error after a while of running the server:

That OOME is not necessarily an indication of a leak.  It could be a sign that you haven't left enough non-heap memory for the number of threads that you are trying to create.  (Or to put it another way, that your thread pool is too big.)

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating a *fixed* thread pool. The `ExecutorService` is not going to release the threads until you terminate the `ExecutorService` itself by calling `ExecutorService.shutdown()` or `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()`.